# exchange a column of many many csv files using awk

Tags: command-line, awk, csv

There is a similar post, but this one is slightly different. I have a csv file in which the second column contains some alphanumeric data. I need to delete this entire column and replace it with a new one. I need to do this for many files in the same directory. The files are named treatables-000.csv, treatables-001.csv, and so one. Here's an example :
Original file:

```
 t ,  group,     1
aaa,  baddata1,  bbb
aab,  baddata1,  bbc
.......
aaad  baddata2   bbb
```

Column 2 needs to be replaced with the column`p1,p2,p3,... p20,p1,p2,..`. It should be of the same length as the original.
How can I do this using the command line? The files may all be of different length.

Comment: It's not clear what the second column should be replaced with, what's the criterium to determine `p1,p2,p3` and the successive values?

Comment: @kos Second column is the group column. Delete the entire column (below the entry group), and replace it with p1-p20 for first twenty rows then again p1-p20 and so on. What is not clear?

Comment: I thought `p1,p2,p3` was the first value and `p20,p1,p2` the second one, my bad. Are the fields really spaced like that? because obviously changing the middle field would misalign the columns. Is that spacing (2 spaces after each column) to kept?

Comment: You are not the only student taking this course.  A very similar question was asked previously here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239311/changing-column-of-multiple-csv-files

Comment: @John1024 Technically it's also the same student. Flagged for closure.

Comment: @John1024 I am the same person who asked that question. But the two questions are different, although similar.

Comment: @kos The second column has the first value $p1$ second value $p2$ third value $p3$... and twenty-first value $p1$. makes sense now? Commas in a csv file serve as delimiters.

Comment: Yes, I got that already (although without the surrounding `$$`, i.e. `p1`, `p2`, `p3`...). Anyway that's minor, I have a working answer already, but I'd like to know if the spacing (two spaces after each comma) is to be retained or if you want no space / a single space / more then two spaces.

Comment: Anyway this question looks exactly like your first one, or at least the answer is going to be the same. If someone already casted a close vote you should agree with the close vote and let this question be closed. I'll post my answer on the other question if you're not happy with the answer you currently have there.

Comment: @kos there is no spacing after the comma. It shows in the input code here just to illustrate these are different columns. Really it is much simpler than what you are thinking, I feel. just delete the entire column, and replace it with the new column!

Comment: I posted my answer in your other question, since although the question are apparently slightly different they're not enough to require a different answer.